# Encountering Exception When Executing Python Script with SET Command and SELECT Statements in MySQL, Despite Successful Database Connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to execute a Python script containing a query with both a SET command and several SELECT statements to retrieve records from a MySQL database. Although the database connection is established successfully, an exception is raised during execution. It's worth noting that the same query executes without issue in SQL IDEs like SQLyog or MySQL Workbench, returning the expected records. However, the Python code encounters an error. Code snippet and error snippet attached below.

[Here is my python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsEF.png)

[Error Encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzQxt.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO @Shubham, Please upload code/snippet instead of image to reproduce the error.